# Creating a new branch (B) from an existing feature branch (A) and merging the old feature branch (A) into develop

Tags: git, bitbucket

Suppose, I have a feature branch (A) that I created from the develop branch and then I create another feature branch (B) from A - can I then decide to merge A back to the develop branch and continue working on branch B and then merge B back to develop? Is that even recommended or are there any potential issues?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended or anything... it's just a thing you *can* do and there's no reason not to do it, as long as you are careful as to what revisions make up each feature when you move them around.... think: when rebasing.

So... just to exemplify.... if you wanted to separate feature b from feature a at a given moment in time, you could do so by doing this:

```
git rebase --onto some-branch featurea featureb
```

You are asking git to move the revisions that make up featureb, disregarding revisions from featurea, on top of some-branch.